# Google API Client - id_token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to make an API that return google user profile with using my token id that I've got from Google Developers Playground (OAuth 2.0). I've read and follow the guidelines, but when I trying to use my code, it says  `id_token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken`. Here is my code :

```
  $id_token = $this->input->post('id_token');
  $id_event = $this->input->post('id_event');

  $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID]);
  $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token); //It's error here
```

At first it's run well but when I try to run it again, the error show up. What should I do?

Here's full error message :

```
Type: LogicException
Message: id_token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken

Filename: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\api\application\vendor\google\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Client.php
Line Number: 702

Backtrace:
    File: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\api\application\controllers\C_android_api.php
    Line: 190
    Function: verifyIdToken

    File: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\api\index.php
    Line: 315
    Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 3):

See my solution [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1289#issuecomment-390046835)

> The following issue "id_token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken" fixed when I provided "email" scope.
>
> i.e., `$client->addScope("email");`
>
> reference and full example here: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/idtoken.php

Hope this helps.